# Telerik ListView Item change Height

Tags: vb.net, listview, telerik, windows-forms-designer

e is an ListView Visual Item and i want to change the row Height but
e.VisualItem.Size = New Size(12, 12)

doesnt work i dont know how to change the Height of an item.

```
Dim Index As Integer = lvPriscus.Items.IndexOf(e.VisualItem.Data)
If Index Mod 2 <> 0 Then
    e.VisualItem.Size = New Size(12, 12)
    e.VisualItem.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(245, 245, 245)
End If
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: There is no Size change

Comment: So no compilation error or exception? Have you stepped through that code and confirmed that it is executed? Have you checked the value of that `Size` property before and after that line is executed?

Comment: Yes no error or exception and yes it is executed and in checked that the value of that Size property before and after that line is executed. I think the code is not right but i found nothing in the internet so...

Comment: The code is defenitly executet